# Magento 1.7.0.2: Transactional Email Not Editing

Tags: magento-1.7, transactional-mail

I am Using Magento 1.7.0.2. When I tried to edit transactional email template, I got this error `Decoding failed: Syntax error`. 
How to Solve it.

Note:
The only particular template is not loading. Other templates are able to edit.

[image: Decoding failed: Syntax error]

Answer (score 0):

Install this module.

https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

It due to PHP7 and magento compablity issue.

```
        <?php
        class Inchoo_PHP7_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
        {
            /** @var string $_moduleName Compatibility for translations, and maybe other stuff which uses module names. */
            protected $_moduleName = 'Mage_Core';
            /**
             * Decodes the given $encodedValue string which is encoded in the JSON format
             *
             * Overridden to prevent exceptions in json_decode
             *
             * @param string $encodedValue
             * @param int $objectDecodeType
             * @return mixed
             * @throws Zend_Json_Exception
             */
            public function jsonDecode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType = Zend_Json::TYPE_ARRAY) {
                switch (true) {
                    case (null === $encodedValue)  : $encodedValue = 'null'; break;
                    case (true === $encodedValue)  : $encodedValue = 'true'; break;
                    case (false === $encodedValue) : $encodedValue = 'false'; break;
                    case ('' === $encodedValue)    : $encodedValue = '""'; break;
                    default    : // do nothing
                }
                return json_decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
                return Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @pathiyar, After Installing this module also getting same error only.

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Comment: yes, cleared cache and reindexed. Note: The only particular template is not loading. Other templates are able to edit.

Comment: just for some time comment this line 

Zend_Json::decode($encodedValue, $objectDecodeType);

from file

app/code/local/Inchoo/PHP7/Helper/Data.php
Than edit same template and remove store_url=\\.
and check again by uncommentiong same line.

Comment: got this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /public_html/deals/shell/inchoo_php7_test.php on line 28`

Comment: After commenting that line also same error only.

Comment: Hey buddy , please check the updated answer.. Update the code of file app/code/local/Inchoo/PHP7/Helper/Data.php

Comment: Hi @padhiyar, I checked with updated code. Still, the error remains. While editing only one template I am getting an error.